# react-native apk crashed when navigate to register and login screen

Tags: react-native

The problem is when I generate signed apk and install it, all other screen work but when I click on the login and register icon in drawer section it crashed without going to login and register screen.

In  debug mode it should perfectly work but in release mode it crashed when I click on the register and login icon.

### register screen

```
import React, { useState,useEffect,useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,TextInput, Dimensions,Image,
TouchableOpacity,ActivityIndicator,StatusBar,Pressable,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {SvgTop2} from '../../components';
import { images,icons, COLORS } from '../../constants';
import  LinearGradient  from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import axios from 'axios';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
import { Context } from '../../components/Context';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import FlashMessage, { showMessage, hideMessage} from "react-native-flash-message";

const Register = (props) => {
    const { navigation,route } = props;
    const [placeholder,setPlaceholder]=React.useState("");
    const [logo,setLogo]=React.useState("  ");
    const [isRegistrationSuccess, setIsRegistrationSuccess ] = useState(false);
    const {storeCredential,setStoreCredential}=useContext(Context);
    const [passwordVisibility, setPasswordVisibility] = useState(true);
    const [rightIcon, setRightIcon] = useState('eye');
   useEffect(()=>{
   getPlaceholderName();
  
  },[]);
     const getPlaceholderName=() => {
        if(route.params.data==1){
           setPlaceholder("Register Ngo Email")
       }else if(route.params.data==2){
          setPlaceholder("Register  volunter Email")
       }else{
           setPlaceholder(" Register  govt Email")
       }
   }
   const handleSignup = (values) => {
   const url = 'http://13.126.22.186/team-engage/public/api/user-registration';
    axios.post(url,values).then((response) => {
      const result = response.data;
        const { status, message } = result;
        if (status == 'false') {
          showMessage({
            message: "something went wrong!.",
            type: "danger",
          })
       } else {
        AsyncStorage.removeItem('MatrusevaCredential')
                    .then((values)=>{
                      setStoreCredential(values);
                    }).catch((error)=>{
                 })
                }
             })
      .catch((error) => {
      });
    }; 
     const handlePasswordVisibility = () => {
      if (rightIcon === 'eye') {
        setRightIcon('eye-slash');
        setPasswordVisibility(!passwordVisibility);
      } else if (rightIcon === 'eye-slash') {
        setRightIcon('eye');
        setPasswordVisibility(!passwordVisibility);
      }
    }
   if (isRegistrationSuccess) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor:COLORS.darkBlue,
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
          <StatusBar barStyle='light' backgroundColor='#002851'/>
        <Image
          source={icons.success}
          style={{
            height: 150,
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            alignSelf: 'center'
          }}
        />
        <Text style={styles.successTextStyle}>
          Registration Successful
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          onPress={() =>navigation.navigate('Login2')}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>Login Now</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
    return (
     <View>
      <ScrollView>
       <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <FlashMessage position="top" />
        <StatusBar barStyle='light' backgroundColor='#002851' />
       <View style={styles.containerSVG}>
       <SvgTop2/>
          <Icon style={{bottom:240,left:-160,color:'white'}}
            name="chevron-circle-left" size={35} color='black'
            onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Login')}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Formik
               initialValues={{ name: '', email: '', mobile:'', password: '', confirmPassword: '',"role":"volunteer" }}
               onSubmit={(values) => {
                 values = { ...values };
                 if (
                   values.email == '' || values.password == '' || values.name == '' || values.mobile == '' || 
                    values.confirmPassword == ''   )
                    {
                  showMessage({
                    message: "Please fill all the fields.",
                    type: "danger",
                  })
                  setSubmitting(false);
                 } else if (values.password !== values.confirmPassword) {
                  showMessage({
                    message: "password do not match.",
                    type: "danger",
                  })
                  
                 } else if(values.mobile ===undefined || values.mobile.length<10){
                  showMessage({
                    message: "please enter a valid phone number!.",
                    type: "danger",
                  })
                  
                 }else{
                  setTimeout(()=>{
                    handleSignup(values);
                    setIsRegistrationSuccess(true);
                   showMessage({
                      message: "successfully register!.",
                      type: "success",
                    })
                   },1000)
                 }
               }}
            >
           {({ handleChange, isSubmitting,handleBlur,handleSubmit,values}) => (
             <>
          <TextInput 
            placeholder="Full name"
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={handleChange('name')}
            onBlur={handleBlur('name')}
            placeholderTextColor="black"
            value={values.name}/>
            
          <TextInput 
            placeholder={placeholder}
            style={styles.textInput}
            type="email"
            placeholderTextColor="black"
            onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
            onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
            keyboardType="email-address"
            value={values.email}/>

          <TextInput 
            placeholder="Contact Number"
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholderTextColor="black"
            onChangeText={handleChange('mobile')}
            onBlur={handleBlur('mobile')}
            value={values.mobile}/>
            
          <TextInput 
            placeholder="Password"
            style={styles.textInput}
            secureTextEntry={passwordVisibility}
            placeholderTextColor="black"
            onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
            onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
            value={values.password}/>
          <Pressable onPress={handlePasswordVisibility}>
          <Icon name={rightIcon} size={22} color="#232323" style={{bottom:35,left:120}}/>
        </Pressable>
          <TextInput 
            placeholder="Confirm Password"
            placeholderTextColor="black"
            style={styles.textInput1}
            secureTextEntry={passwordVisibility}
            onChangeText={handleChange('confirmPassword')}
            onBlur={handleBlur('confirmPassword')}
            value={values.confirmPassword}/>
            <Pressable onPress={handlePasswordVisibility}>
          <Icon name={rightIcon} size={22} color="#232323" style={{bottom:60,left:120}}/>
        </Pressable>
       
    {!isSubmitting && (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.containers}
         onPress={handleSubmit}
         >
            <LinearGradient
                colors={['#002851', '#002851']}
                start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
                end={{x: 1, y: 1}}    
                style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>SIGN UP</Text>
            </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       )}
        {isSubmitting && (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.containers}
         onPress={handleSubmit}
         >
            <LinearGradient
               colors={['#002851', '#002851']}
                start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
                end={{x: 1, y: 1}}    
                style={styles.button}
            >
               <ActivityIndicator size="large" color='white'/>  
            </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        </>
           )}
        </Formik>
        </View>
      </View> 
   </ScrollView>
      </View>

     
    );
  };
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        bottom:50
    },
     mainContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
        flex: 1,
      },
      containerSVG: {
        width: width,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
       bottom:70
        
      },
      textInput: {
        padding: 10,
        paddingStart: 30,
        width: '80%',
        height: 50,
        marginTop: 20,
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color:COLORS.black
      },
      textInput1: {
        padding: 10,
        paddingStart: 30,
        width: '80%',
        height: 50,
        marginTop: 20,
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color:COLORS.black,
        bottom:20
      },
      containers: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: 200,
       },
    text: {
      fontSize: 18,
      color: '#fff',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    button: {
        width: '150%',
        height: 60,
        borderRadius: 25,
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    buttonStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#7DE24E',
      borderWidth: 0,
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      borderColor: '#7DE24E',
      height: 40,
      width:150,
      alignItems: 'center',
      borderRadius: 30,
      marginLeft:width*0.3,
      marginRight: 35,
      marginTop: 20,
      marginBottom: 20,
    },
    buttonTextStyle: {
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      paddingVertical: 10,
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    successTextStyle: {
      color: 'white',
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontSize: 18,
      padding: 30,
      fontWeight:'bold'
    },
     
}); 

//make this component available to the app
export default Register;
```

### login screen

````
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React,{useRef,useEffect,useState,useContext} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,TextInput, Dimensions,Image,
ActivityIndicator,TouchableOpacity,StatusBar,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {Sheet,SvgTop} from '../../components';
import {icons, images,COLORS} from '../../constants';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
import RBSheet from "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet";
import  {Formik} from 'formik'
import  LinearGradient  from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import {SvgTop2} from '../../components';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Context } from '../../components/Context';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import FlashMessage, {
  showMessage,
  hideMessage
} from "react-native-flash-message";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
const Login2 = () => {

   const navigation=useNavigation();
    const refRBSheet = useRef();
    const {storeCredential,setStoreCredential}=useContext(Context);
    const [placeholder,setPlaceholder]=React.useState("");
    const [logo,setLogo]=React.useState("  ");
    
    
   const handleLogin = (value) => {
    const url = 'http://13.126.22.186/team-engage/public/api/user-login';
      axios.post(url,value)
        .then((response) => {
          const result = response.data;
          const { status, message} = result;
          let value1 =result.data.user;
          if (status == 'false') {
            showMessage({
              message: "Invalid credential",
              type: "danger",
            })
          
          } else {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('MatrusevaCredential',JSON.stringify(value1));
         setStoreCredential(value1);
            
         }
      })
        .catch((error) => {
        });
    };
   return (
     
     <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
           <StatusBar barStyle='light' backgroundColor='#002851' />
          <View style={styles.containerSVG}>
            <SvgTop2/>
             <Icon style={{bottom:300,left:-150,color:'white'}}
               name="chevron-circle-left" size={35} color='black'
               onPress={()=>navigation.goBack('Logins')}
               />
                <FlashMessage position="top"/>
            {/* <Image source style={{bottom:20}}/> */}
          <Formik
          initialValues={{ email: '', password: '',"role":"volunteer"  }}
           onSubmit={(value, { setSubmitting }) => {
            if (value.email == '' || value.password == '') {
              showMessage({
                message: "All field must be require !!",
                type: "danger",
              })
            setSubmitting(false);
            }else if (value.password.length < 8) {
              showMessage({
                message: "Invalid Password or Email",
                type: "danger",
              })
              return false;
          }
            else{
               handleLogin(value);
               showMessage({
                message: "Successfully Logged in",
                type: "success",  
              })
               
           }
        }}>
          {({ handleChange, handleBlur,isSubmitting,handleSubmit,values}) => (
             <>
             {/* <Text style={{color:'red',top:10,right:60}}type={messageType}>{message}</Text> */}
             <TextInput
                       name="email"
                       placeholder="volunteer email address"
                       style={styles.textInput}
                       onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                       onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                       value={values.email}
                       placeholderTextColor='black'
                       keyboardType="email-address"
                    />
                 <TextInput
                       name="password"
                       placeholder="Password"
                       placeholderTextColor='black'
                       style={styles.textInput}
                       onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                       onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
                       value={values.password}
                       secureTextEntry

                     />
              
              <TouchableOpacity style={{activeOpacity:0.5}}>
             <Text style={styles.forgotPassword} onPress={() => refRBSheet.current.open()} >Forgot your password?</Text>
             <RBSheet
             ref={refRBSheet}
             closeOnDragDown={true}
             closeOnPressMask={true}
             height={1000}
              openDuration={250}
             customStyles={{
               wrapper: {
                 backgroundColor: "transparent"
               },
           }}
             >
             <Sheet />
             </RBSheet>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             {!isSubmitting && (

              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.containers}
               onPress={handleSubmit}
               
                 >
                 <LinearGradient
                     // Button Linear Gradient
                     colors={['#002851', '#002851']}
                     start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
                     end={{x: 1, y: 1}}    
                     style={{
                       width: '140%',
                       height: 50,
                       borderRadius: 20,
                       padding: 10,
                       alignItems: 'center',
                       justifyContent: 'center',
                     }}
                 >
                   <Text style={styles.text}>SIGN IN</Text>
                     </LinearGradient>
               </TouchableOpacity>
             )}
 {isSubmitting && (
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.containers}
 onPress={handleSubmit}>
   <LinearGradient
      colors={['#9900EF', '#00d084ff']}
       start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
       end={{x: 1, y: 1}}    
       style={{
         width: '140%',
         height: 50,
         borderRadius: 25,
         padding: 10,
         alignItems: 'center',
         justifyContent: 'center',
       }} >
       <ActivityIndicator size="large" color='white' />  
           </LinearGradient>
       </TouchableOpacity>
)}
             <TouchableOpacity>
                 <Text style={styles.forgotPassword} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Login')}>Don't have an account? <Text style={{color:'red'}}>Register</Text></Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             </>
                 )}
             </Formik>

</View>
</View>
</ScrollView>

    );
};

// define your styles
const styles =StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: {
       
        flex: 1,
      },
      container: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        top:-30
      },
      containerSVG: {
        width: width,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },

    todo: {
       
        color: '#34434D',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
      containers: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: 200,
        marginTop: 20,
    },

    text: {
      fontSize: 14,
      color: '#fff',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    button: {
        width: '90%',
        height: 70,
        borderRadius: 25,
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
      subTitle: {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'gray',
        marginTop:30
      },
     
      textInput: {
        padding: 10,
        paddingStart: 30,
        width: '80%',
        height: 50,
        marginTop: 20,
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color:COLORS.black
      },
       errorText: {
         fontSize: 10,
         color: 'red',
       },
      errorTextStyle: {
        color: 'red',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 24,
      },
      forgotPassword: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: 'black',
        marginTop: 20,
        fontWeight:'bold'
        
      },
    
});

//make this component available to the app
export default Login2;

``` 
 ## route ##

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {
    MyEvent,
     Splash,
     Location,
     Profile,
     Program,
     Login,
    Register,
    Notification,
    CountDown,
    Reward,
    Certificate,
    Steps,
    Login2,
    ChangePss,
    Scanner,
    Success,
    Logins,
    OnboardingScreen,
    Announcement,
    Grievance
    } from '../screen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
 import { createStackNavigator,TransitionSpecs, HeaderStyleInterpolators, } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Context } from '../components/Context';
import ProfileDrawer from './Drawer';
 const Stack = createStackNavigator();


 const MyTransition = {
     gestureDirection: 'vertical',
    transitionSpec: {
      open: TransitionSpecs.TransitionIOSSpec,
      close: TransitionSpecs.TransitionIOSSpec,
    },
    headerStyleInterpolator: HeaderStyleInterpolators.forFade,
    cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current, next, layouts }) => {
      return {
        cardStyle: {
          transform: [
            {
              translateX: current.progress.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: [layouts.screen.width, 0],
              }),
            },
           ],
        },
        overlayStyle: {
          opacity: current.progress.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 0.1],
          }),
        },
      };
    },
  };
 const Routes = () => {
 
  return (
      <Context.Consumer>
       {({storeCredential})=>(
    <NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator
     screenOptions={{
         headerShown: false,
        ...MyTransition,
       
       
     }}
     initialRouteName={'Splash'}
      >
  
        <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={Splash} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MyEvent" component={MyEvent} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Location" component={Location} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ProfileDrawer" component={ProfileDrawer} options={{header: () => null}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Program" component={Program} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingScreen" component={OnboardingScreen} />
       {storeCredential ? (
     <>
       <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} /> 
       <Stack.Screen name="CountDown" component={CountDown} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Notification" component={Notification} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Reward" component={Reward} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Success" component={Success} />
       <Stack.Screen name="ChangePss" component={ChangePss} /> 
       <Stack.Screen name="Certificate" component={Certificate} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Scanner" component={Scanner} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Steps" component={Steps} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Announcement" component={Announcement}/>
       <Stack.Screen name="Grievance" component={Grievance} />
       </>
      ) : (
    <>
    <Stack.Screen  name="Login" component={Login} />
     <Stack.Screen name="Login2" component={Login2} />
     <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register}/>
     <Stack.Screen name="Logins" component={Logins}/>
    </>
      )
  }
 </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
 
 )}
</Context.Consumer>
       
    )
  
}

export default Routes;

```

## package.json ##

```
{
  "name": "matruseva",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.17",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "^14.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "haversine": "^1.1.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "npm": "^8.5.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.3",
    "react-native-auto-scale-text": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-auto-size-text": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "1.1271.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-confetti-cannon": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-copilot": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "0.25.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.29.4",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-shadow-cards": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-textarea": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.17.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.16.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.5",
    "bundle": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.5.0",
    "false": "^0.0.4",
    "jest": "^27.4.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```
````

Comment: Is there a stack trace or similar for the crash?

Comment: no the error is svg.i have used in svg in my login and register screen..when user click on buttton then redirect to login or register screen at that time apk should be crashed..i got the solution..the solution is by adding this -keep public class com.horcrux.svg.** {*;}  the error gone....

Answer (score 1):

You can check the crash logs in Android studio console. It may help you to find the cause of the crash. Or the other solution is to integrate Crashlytics SDK.